# Sum of Interior Angles of a Circle

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

I have been asked to verify the local version of the Gauss-Bonnet theorem for a paraboloid, I am confused about how to work out the sum of (π - interior angles) of the vertices at boundary ∂R which is a circle at the point where z=a ( a constant). As it's a circle I assume there is only one vertice, where the start and end points join. But I am unsure of what the angle would be, any ideas? My guess would be π but i am unsure at how to verify this.

Comment: Vertices and angles make no sense in this context. Yoy have to work with the curvature of curves. What versions of the Gauss-Bonnet theorem do you know?